# postgresql in id field is null then autoincrement

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a primary key serial field.  The application I am using to make changes sends null to this field for new records.  Is there a way to force the autoincrement to be set for the primary key when the value coming in is null.

To clarify.  If I do the following

```
 insert into junk values (null,'abc');
```

On a table that looks like this:

```
 create table junk (id serial, txt text);
```

I would like for the record to be created and the id field to auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

`Serial` is already implies autoincrement, just skip this field in insert query:

```
INSERT INTO junk (txt) VALUES ('abc')
```